# unable to create service java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, phone-state-listener

I implement a sensorEventListener which on shake changes ringer mode. I am using a service so that i can change the ringer mode from outside the activity whenever i like. This is my code for the service i am using-

```
package com.nadeem.shakeit;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class service extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private long lastUpdate;
AudioManager am;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

/*@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent == null) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}*/
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        getAccelerometer(event);
    }

}

private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] values = event.values;
    // Movement
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
            / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (accelationSquareRoot >= 5) //
    {
        if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
            return;
        }
        lastUpdate = actualTime;
        int ringerMode = am.getRingerMode();
        if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        } else if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) {
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        } else {
            am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
}
}
```

when i open the app it force closes. Logcat shows:-

```
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to       create service com.nadeem.shakeit.service: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2076)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at com.nadeem.shakeit.service.onCreate(service.java:21)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2066)
07-15 12:04:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(22092):    ... 10 more
```

Edit-After instantiating the sensorManager again i am getting a nullPointerException. The stack trace is-

```
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at com.nadeem.shakeit.service.getAccelerometer(service.java:64)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at com.nadeem.shakeit.service.onSensorChanged(service.java:43)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SensorManager.java:529)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-15 12:35:45.280: E/AndroidRuntime(22469):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sensorManager` is uninitiallised. You are missing something like this in your `onCreate()`

```
sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your sensorManager variable.

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just declared the `SensorManager` reference variable , currently it holds a `null` reference , where have you instantiated it ?

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;
```

Calling any method on this `null` reference will throw a `NullPointerException`:

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this,
        sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

You need to initialize it in `onCreate()`:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Even your `AudioManager am;` refers to `null` , you need to initialize it before invoking any methods on it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did what you said. After instantiating, it again gives a NullPointerException.

Comment: give us the stacktrace ?

Comment: What is the line at `service.java:64` ?

Comment: Its an AudioManager. I was trying to get the ringer mode. I did not initialize the Audiomanager object. Now it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens if there is a property that tries to use the superclass before its initialization (which is always, since the properties are always defined before the initialization of Context).

Kotlin solution:

The best workaround (I found) is to mark it as lazy

```kotlin
    private val notificationManager by lazy { getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java) }
```

This way the property won't be defined until it's called. And when it'll be called, by that time the app would've already started so the Context will no longer be null.

Another way is to mark the property as `lateinit`, and then assign it at onCreate

```kotlin
    private lateinit var notificationManager :NotificationManager

    override fun onCreate() {
        notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
       
    }
```